# Streaming file through php server from amazon s3

Tags: php, amazon-s3, streaming

I would like to stream a file from S3 to the client browser using PHP. I could manage to do it but I have a problem with large files. First, it takes all the memory available for the session and end up with a "Memory exhausted" error.
Second, when reaching "fread(...)" for the first time, it hangs almost 1 min for a 50Mo file before to start sending to the browser. How can I handle these 2 problems? Here is my code.

```
$client->register_stream_wrapper();

    if($stream = fopen('s3://' . S3_BUCKET . '/' . $destination_s3, 'r'))
    {
        //Send file to browser.
        header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
        header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
        header("Cache-control: no-store");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
        header("Content-Type: " . $file_type);
        while (!feof($stream)) {
            echo fread($stream, 1024);
            flush();
        }
        fclose($stream);
    }
```